# Updating or refreshing controls with c#

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, refresh

I've made a winforms project that lets me search and add into an SQL database using SQLite.
One form has a TreeView and CheckedBoxList that contain the symptoms or species related to an illness. These controls are filled programmatically with their own public non-static function.
Another form lets me edit the database, specifically adding a node to the TreeView or list of symptoms. After editing the database, it activates the function to update the mentioned controls.
I hoped it would immediately update the control, but it doesn't.
A few solutions I've tried:
`this.Refresh();`
`this.Invalidate();`
`this.BeginUpdate();` and
`this.EndUpdate();`
I've done them separately or all at once; tried it for "this.", "Form1." and "treeView1."; but none managed to update the form or control.

Then I thought 'maybe updating the control on Form1 from Form2 is different from updating itself on Form1', so I added Form1.treeView1.Nodes to make sure it focussed on the correct control.
This still did not show the newly added node or checkBoxList Item.

Form1:

```
using System.Data.SQLite;
// ///
public void UpdateCheckedBoxList(SQLiteConnection conn) {
    SQLiteDataReader sqlite_datareader;
    SQLiteCommand sqlite_cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Species; ";
    sqlite_datareader = sqlite_cmd.ExecuteReader();

    List<string> myreader = new List<string> { };
    while (sqlite_datareader.Read()) {
        myreader.Add(sqlite_datareader.GetString(1));
    }
    string[] Species = myreader.ToArray();
    checkedListBox1.Items.AddRange(Species);
    this.Refresh();
}
```

Form2:

```
SQLiteCommand sqlite_conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" +
            "C:\\Users\\" + Environment.UserName + "\\Documents\\ddx project\\ddx-database.db; Version = 3; New = True; Compress = True;");
sqlite_conn.Open();
new Form1().UpdateCheckedBoxList(sqlite_conn);
```

Comment: Did you try refreshing the checkedListBox itself instead of the form?

Comment: Yes I've tried it for the treeView, Form, and checkedListBox, but none updated, sadly. Only when I activate the function from within the same form does it update the form/control.

Comment: This `new Form1().UpdateComboBox(sqlite_conn);` creates a new `Form1`, not the one you're dealing with. Either pass `Form1` to `Form2` through a parametrized ctor, or replace that line with `Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form1>().First().UpdateComboBox(sqlite_conn);`.

Comment: "Refreshing" is generally just going to repaint the control. Proper databinding will allow changes to flow thru with no heroics on your part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [dr. null](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14171304/dr-null)'s comment, I managed to update the controls. They mentioned my use of `new Form1();`, creating a new Form1 instead of trying to update the opened Form1. This is a solution:

```
Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form1>().First().UpdateComboBox(sqlite_conn);

Application.OpenForms.OfType<FormName>().First().formSpecificFunction(args);
```